# Flask: Stuck with qlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

So Im writing a delivery tracker and I got to where im starting to add deliverys to the db but I keep encountering not null constraints failure.

This is the model

```
class Delivery(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    tag = db.Column(db.String(4), nullable=False, unique=False)
    product = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=False)
    quanity = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, unique=False)
    po_num = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=False)
    tracking = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True, unique=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True, unique=False)
    signed = db.Column(db.String(2), nullable=False, unique=False)
    tickprojnum = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True, unique=False)
    location = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True, unique=False)
```

Here is the route that processes it

```
    form = CreateDelivery()
    if form.validate_on_submit:
        delivery = Delivery(
            tag = form.tag.data,
            product = form.product.data,
            quanity = form.quanity.data,
            po_num = form.po_num.data,
            tracking = form.tracking.data,
            date = form.date.data,
            signed = form.signed.data,
            tickprojnum = form.tickprojnum.data,
            location = form.location.data
        )
        db.session.add(delivery)
        db.session.commit()
```

And as a check I  got the schema from the SQLite tool

```
CREATE TABLE delivery (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        tag VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL, 
        product VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
        quanity INTEGER NOT NULL,
        po_num VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        tracking VARCHAR,
        date DATETIME,
        signed VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
        tickprojnum VARCHAR,
        location VARCHAR,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

I updated the model but as such I rebuilt the DB file so that it would have the correct schema but it still gives the not null constraint error. Any advice on how to fix this is much appreciated. If any more information is required, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot a set of parenthesis

```
if form.validate_on_submit:
```

should have been

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
```

Comment: You can edit your original post by click on the 'edit' button below the post

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it happens when the you are trying to access any column that is not made in your database file or sometimes when you are not accessing the column you have made.
So to handle it recreate the database file using *create_all()* command.
It might solve your problem.